# BERT Optimization for Production

Tags: nlp, bert, transformer, semantic-similarity

I'm  using BERT to transform text into 768 dim vector, It's multilingual :

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2')
```

Now i want to put the model into production but the embedding time is too much and i want to reduce and optimize the model **to reduce the embedding time** What are the libraries that enable me to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start by using torchscript, it may require changing ur whole code, and  switching to transformers( by loading the backbone of the model and the last layers) so basically u get out from GIL interpreter, coz it does not support multithreading.
by with torchscript u can run ur model in c++ env,
there's also onnx which I believe it enhances performance.

if ur use case is not a real-time and you are using an API, you can use a queue mechanism like rabbitmq

Comment: What is the difference between real time and an api ?                                           "so basically u get out from GIL interpreter, coz it does not support multithreading" can you illustrate more what you mean ? @SADAK